# Join two MySQL Tables and display combined data

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database.

cat - catid, catname
articles - id, catid, content

so what i want to display is category name (catname) and how many articles are there in that category.

This is my code but it dosent work.

```
$query = "SELECT cat.cname,  COUNT(articles.cat_id)".
"FROM cat, articles ".
    "GROUP BY cat_id";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['cname']. " - ". $row['COUNT(cat_id)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Any help will be most aprriceated. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is a 1:many relationship. i.e. 1 Category -> Many articles.

The best way to do this is to create a third table, an adjacency list.

Keep your 'category_id' and 'article_id' unique in tables 'cat' and 'article'.

In your third table you define the 1 : many relationships.

```
Table 3: cat_articles

adj_id    cat_id    art_id
1         1         1
2         1         2
3         2         3
4         2         4
5         3         5
```

Now join the tables:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `cat_articles` adj ".
       "LEFT JOIN (`cat` cat, `articles` art)".
       "ON (cat.cat_id = adj.cat_id AND art.art_id = adj.art_id) ";
```

This takes the adjacency table, preserves it's format(due to left join) and appends the tables `article` and `category` to it, giving you a categorised table of all your articles. You can now use `mysql_fetch_array()` to get your results.

#### Edit: reference first comment, displaying number of rows

You can either, as you have done, use SQL's function `COUNT` to return a count of a specific column.

Or, with PHP, run the query, and then use `mysql_num_rows($result)` to return the number of rows SQL has in its buffer.

Alternatively, retrieve results using `mysql_fetch_array($result)` and use `count` to return the number of paired values in the array.

Comment: it works. but there is a small problem. i cant get it to count the amount of articles and if the cat have 0 articles it doesn't show up

Answer (score 1):

Using mysql_fetch_array:

```
$query = "SELECT cat.cname,  COUNT(articles.cat_id)".
"FROM cat, articles ".
    "GROUP BY cat_id";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row[0]. " - ". $row[1];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

mysql_fetch_array returns a number indexed array (0,1,2,3,4, ..)

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` defaults to returning both a numericaly indexed array AND associative array. To specifically ask for a numerical array you would set the return type: `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cat.cname,  COUNT(articles.cat_id) artcount
FROM cat, articles WHERE c.cat_id = articles.cat_id
GROUP BY cat.cat_id
```

I guess you are missing the join clause. Unless you are joining the tables correctly you are creating a "cartesian product".

Get the rows "$row['cname'] and $row['artcount'].

Comment: this works but if the articles are "0" in any category it dosent show the "category name - 0"

Comment: You need to do a left outer join (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_join#Left_outer_join) then: SELECT cat.cname,  COUNT(articles.cat_id) artcount
FROM cat LEFT JOIN articles ON cat.cat_id = articles.cat_id
GROUP BY cat.cat_id;